# Kotlin Flow: not enough information to infer type variable inside Flow's builder function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-flow

I have this extension function:

```
inline operator fun <reified T : Any> SharedPreferences.get(key: String, defaultValue: T? = null): T? {
    return when (T::class) {
        String::class -> getString(key, defaultValue as? String ?: "") as T
        Int::class -> getInt(key, defaultValue as? Int ?: -1) as T
        Boolean::class -> getBoolean(key, defaultValue as? Boolean ?: false) as T
        Float::class -> getFloat(key, defaultValue as? Float ?: -1f) as T
        Long::class -> getLong(key, defaultValue as? Long ?: -1) as T
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
   }
}
```

I'm able to use it without any issue:

[image]

But when I use it inside the Flow's builder function I'm getting this error:

> Not enough information to infer parameter T

[image]

Comment: Oops, I've figured out it's not a compile error, I can assemble the project.

Comment: You need to enable the new type inference in your build script or the settings.

Comment: @RuNo280 can you please share how you fixed this